# Provide console (stdin) input to program when compiled and run with :make?

Tags: makeprg

Is it possible to run a blocking input statement in your code when it is run from within the vim buffer? For example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
int main(void) {
    int x;
    std::cin >> x;
    std::cout << x;
}
```

I am using a simple make command:

```
:setlocal makeprg=g++\ %\ &&\ ./a.out
```

But of course when I run the program with `:make`, the `cin >> x` statement doesn't block and the variable takes whatever garbage value it was initialized with. What could be a good way of going about this?

Comment: I'd not run the program with `:make` but use `:terminal a.out` instead. Maybe define a mapping that runs both commands?

Comment: Funny thing is I cannot reproduce this issue. It blocks until I input something which is also printed. I'm currently on a  Debian machine with (g)vim 8.2.

Answer (score 2):

When the `make` command trigger the program (here `g++`) it doesn't link `std:in` with an interactive prompt like a terminal program would do.

I believe you have two solutions:

- Run your program within a terminal
- Prepare the input in a file (`prepared_input.in`) and redirect it to your program (`yourprogram < prepared_input.in > a.out`)

The second is not interactive. It is the only way I know we can pass an input to a program started by the `:make` command.